# Do (Instances of) Static Nested Classes Have Access to Outer Static Variables?

Tags: java

The following yields an error:

```
class A {

    static int apple = 5;

    static class StaticNestedSubClassOfA {
    //...
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String str[]) {
    A.StaticNestedSubClassOfA b = new A.StaticNestedSubClassOfA();
    System.out.println("Apple: " + b.apple);
    }
}
```

> **ERROR:**
>
> ```
>   Test.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>
>       System.out.println("Apple: " + b.apple);
>
>                       ^
>
>     symbol:   variable apple
>
>     location: variable b of type StaticNestedSubClassOfA
>
>   1 error
> ```

But doesn't `StaticNestedSubClassOfA` have access to the static variable `apple`? (I suppose this doesn't mean that objects spawned from `StaticNestedSubClassOfA` have access to `apple` *through* their instances?)

Comment: Why not refer to it as `A.apple`, regardless of context?

Comment: `StaticNestedSubClassOfA` has access to `A.apple`, but that's not what you are trying to do. You're trying to access a field named `apple` from a reference expression of type `StaticNestedSubClassOfA`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an `A.apple` in the class `Test` This has no chance of working.

When A is compiled it doesn't know how it will be accessed from all possible classes and cannot generate the access methods required to make this work.

The JVM doesn't allow access to private members between classes. Instead the `javac` compiler adds methods for accesses in the same `java` class file under the outer class. This is why you see methods like `access$200` in the call stack some times. An class accessed a private member from another class via a generated accessor method. If you are in an unrelated class, you can't access private fields, nor could the javac implement a means for you to do so without creating all possible accessors in advance (which it doesn't do)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could think of to get this to work.

```
public class Outer
{
   private static int apples = 5;

   public static class Inner {
      public int getApples() { return Outer.apples; } 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();
      System.out.println( inner.getApples() );
   }
}
```

As far as the run time is concerned, `Outer` and `Inner` are two separate classes.  The idea that they are nested is a fiction maintained by the compiler.  Thus at run time there is really no way for the compiler to access `Outer` by using `Inner`.

Because they share a scope, however, the compiler *does* allow `Inner` to access private methods and fields in `Outer`.  But that's a trick the compiler can pull off without the run time's help.  Other tricks, like accessing the field directly by name as you are trying to do, aren't possible.